# How can I get VS Code Flutter mode working again?

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

My Windows machine crashed while VS Code was updating itself. Now Flutter/Dart mode no longer works, i.e. no syntax coloring or intellisense, no debug support etc.

I have a) deleted the VS Code cache (AppData/Roaming/Code/Cache) b) reinstalled VSCode c) reinstalled Flutter and Dart extensions, but no joy. Flutter doctor says everything is OK.

For what it's worth, Python mode still works.

Has anyone seen this?

Answer (score 0):

I deleted the Flutter and Dart extensions on disk in the `dart-code.*` folders in `%USERPROFILE%\.vscode\extensions`, resinstalled the extensions, and everything is back to normal.